# What should be modified in C++ source to generate control flow graph showing name of functions and operators as well?

Tags: c++, llvm, graphviz, code-analysis, control-flow-graph

There is my C++ program to build a CFG presentation as a `png` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cstring> 

int partitionFunc(std::string &str, int startInd, int endInd)
{   
    int primIndex = startInd;
    int pivotVal = str[endInd];
    for(int i = startInd; i < endInd; i++) {
         if(str[i] <= pivotVal) {             
             char tempIn = str[i];             
             str[i] = str[primIndex];             
             str[primIndex] = tempIn;             
             primIndex++; 
         }
    }

    char tempOut = str[primIndex];
    str[primIndex] = str[endInd]; 
    str[endInd] = tempOut;
    
    return primIndex;
}

void runQsort(std::string &str, int startInd, int endIndex)
{
    if(startInd < endIndex) {        
        int primIndex = partitionFunc(str, startInd, endIndex);        
        runQsort(str, startInd, primIndex - 1);        
        runQsort(str, primIndex, endIndex);        
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

       
    std::array<std::string, 6> verbs = { "alternative", "destination", "airlines", "turbulence", "contribution", "ultimate" };      
    
    std::string selected; 
    int option = 14;
    int endIndex;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:            
            selected = verbs[0];            
            break;
        case 2:
            selected = verbs[1];             
            break;
        case 3:
            selected = verbs[2];              
            break;
        case 4:
            selected = verbs[3]; 
            break;
        case 5:
            selected = verbs[4];            
            break;   
        default:
            selected = verbs[5];            
            break;            
    }  
      
    runQsort(selected, 0, selected.length() - 1);

    int x = 0;

    while(x < selected.length()) {        
        std::cout << selected[x];         
        x++;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To enable a visualization of that, I process the whole code using `clang++`, `llvm` to parse source to  `dot` format:

```
clang -emit-llvm main.cpp -c -o main.bc
opt --dot-cfg-only main.bc
```

Lastly, this command to be executed to see graph as a flowchart:

```
dot -Tpng .main.dot -o main.png
```

The problem I struggle is appearing percent characters in the output file while function and operator identifiers are missing:

[image: trash22]

It's hardly enough to distinguish specific blocks as they are present in the source block. I would eliminate those embarrassing characters for seeing identifiers as they are put in the `cpp` file. What instructions must be added here to do that (or what resources can be recommended to have some familiarity with this subject)? I would prefer to keep on parsing with `clang++/llvm` if it's an available option after editing source appropriately.

Comment: I think what you want is to improve clang's choice of names for the IR values it generates, and base them more on the source code's naming. Clang is open source, you can write and submit a patch.

Answer (score 0):

LLVM uses [Static Single Assignment (SSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) to represent the source in its intermediate representation(IR). This requires LLVM to **add** more SSA variables to the IR. These will be numbered. But you preserve your source variable names by including the flag `-fno-discard-value-names`.